# req.body returns empty object when posting using form data in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, forms, post, express

I'm doing a post request to '/' with a simple text input and expecting to see the data entered in req.body.course. When console logging req.body.course, I am getting an empty object back.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head><title>New Course</title></head>
    <body>
      <form id="myform" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="course" id="mytext" />
        <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" />
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**SERVER**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var course = req.body.course; 
    res.send(course);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log("Server is listening on port", 4000);
});
```

**OUTPUT OF REQ.BODY**

```
{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to tell in headers what is the MIME type of your request
just add in request.

```
 Content-Type='application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the urlencoded middleware.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
```

or

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}))
```

This parses URL encoded bodies since your request format is urlencoded.

You can refer to [bodyparser urlencoded](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) documentation.